# Open PowerPoint in Iphone/Ipad and display it in my application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to write application which will be able to display MS Word docs, MS PowerPoint presentations(ppt). Is there some kind of support for those formats. I know that mail application can open PowerPoint. 
If there is no support for it what approach should i take ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For opening *anything* (PDF, Pages, Word, Numbers, Excel, Images etc) that the Mail.app or Safari can open, you usually use the `UIWebView`.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 320.0F, 480.0F)];
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.something.com/myFile.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

More info here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html

**iPhone 2.2.1 supports:**

```
* Excel (.xls)
* Keynote (.key.zip)
* Numbers (.numbers.zip)
* Pages (.pages.zip)
* PDF (.pdf)
* Powerpoint (.ppt)
* Word (.doc)
```

**iPhone 3.0 (the min version required to get into App store today?) adds support to:**

```
* Rich Text Format (.rtf)
* Rich Text Format Directory (.rtfd.zip) 
* Keynote '09 (.key)
* Numbers '09 (.numbers) Pages '09 (.pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's relatively easy. UIWebView is able to load office documents.

All you have to do is get a URL to your file (this can be anywhere--the app bundle, the documents directory, the internet, etc.), and have UIWebView load it with `-loadRequest`

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIWebView to display documents.

Or There are two ways to preview documents: one is to use UIDocumentInteractionController's preview API, the other is directly use QLPreviewController.

Check this link from Apple for more details and source code-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2