# how to access/generate .ppt file through an IOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

After seeing apple's keynote and other similar applications, I would like to prepare an app which makes presentation(.ppt file) and try to add some other things for an IOS application. But i don't know how & from where i should start from programming side or if any,

Please can anyone give suggestions regarding this feature/functionality.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open PowerPoint in Iphone/Ipad and display it in my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853346/open-powerpoint-in-iphone-ipad-and-display-it-in-my-application)

Comment: Note that the other question concerns displaying PowerPoint documents.  Authoring and saving that format are far too broad of topics to be answered in a single question here.